# How to switch master server and warm standby (with streaming replication) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.1

I would like to know what is the way to switch the role of 2 servers when using warm standby?

I have 2 servers : `S_1` and `S_2`, and at a time T, `S_1` is the master server and `S_2` is a warm standby with streaming replication.

At a later moment, I would like to switch `S_2` become the master server and `S_1` the warm standby.

What do I have to do to switch roles ?

Comment: a *warm* standby or a *hot* standby?  In Postgres, "warm standby" is usually used to refer to a second server which is keeping up to date, but not accepting connections.

Comment: Yes, the second server is a warm standby, and I like to know what steps are needed to switch master and warm standby mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that currently you *cannot* demote a master to a standby.  Doing so will corrupt your database!

The basic documentation for doing this is at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby-failover.html

However the basic thing is you can't switch these other than:

1. Turn off primary
2. Promote secondary
3. *Rebuild* former primary as new secondary off the new primary.

Comment: These days `pg_rewind` can be used to turn the former master into a standby of the new master much more quickly than a complete rebuild. Previously rsync or similar would have been a quicker way to do this.

Comment: If you are on a sufficiently high version of PostgreSQL.  This specified 9.1 which would have been too old.

Comment: @ChrisTravers which version is sufficient?

Comment: @ChrisTravers Why we need to turn off primary? Can step 1 skipped?

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop the primary service

> systemctl stop postgresql ( This command might be different on your OS )

2. login to the secondary and promote it to primary ( -D is for the data directory )

> pg_ctl promote -D /opt/pgsql/data

3. Now at this point you need to change the settings on the old primary to become the new replica and start the service again

Comment: What if we don't have `pg_ctl`? It's not installed on Ubuntu, at least it's not on the path.

Comment: How can we find where the data directory is?

Comment: Ubuntu has it but it's not in the default `PATH`. Try `dpkg -S pg_ctl` to locate it. It's probably in `/usr/lib/postgresql/$MAJORVERSION/bin/pg_ctl`. On Ubuntu, you're expected to use `pg_ctlcluster` instead.

Comment: Note that you MUST NOT start the old primary/master server without `standby.signal` file created in the data directory or it cannot be added as hot-standby replica for the new master because files change. As long as new master has seen *every* transaction that the old master had executed before it was successfully shutdown, it can be attached as a slave to the new master because new master will do timeline change during `pg_ctl promote` and keep all the data in WAL log files. Note that you must have `wal_level = replica` and big enough `wal_keep_segments` on the new master (/old slave).

Answer (score -2):

PostgreSQL server can be promoted to master using below command:

pg_ctl promote -D

PostgreSQL server can be demoted to slave (post promotion using above command) by deleting/moving 'recovery.done' file @ /data dir. And restating the the server.

Comment: Demoting a server to a slave isn't as simple as this in general; `pg_rewind` exists for this purpose.